# Wordpress SQL statement to filter by meta_value

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm using the following code to export a custom post type member, with custom fields, to a CSV file. The member list includes users who are not of a certain member type "member" with a value of 0 or 1. I would like to filter the list to only export where "member" equals 1, but cannot figure out how to modify the statement below to do so.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *

FROM wp_posts (

SELECT 
    #`wp_posts`.`ID`,

    MAX( CASE WHEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'first_name'
    THEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`
    END ) AS `First Name`,

    MAX( CASE WHEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'last_name'
    THEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`
    END ) AS `Last Name`,

    MAX( CASE WHEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'phone_number'
    THEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`
    END ) AS `Phone Number`,

    MAX( CASE WHEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'email_address'
    THEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`
    END ) AS `Email Address`,

    MAX( CASE WHEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'member'
    THEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`
    END ) AS `Member`

FROM `wp_posts`

LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON ( `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` )

WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_status` = 'publish'

AND `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'member'

GROUP BY `wp_posts`.`ID`

ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`post_title` ASC

) AS `t` WHERE 1 =1
");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to add

```
HAVING MAX( CASE WHEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'member'
THEN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`else 0
END ) = 1
```

after

```
GROUP BY
```

Its hard to tell structure for wp_posts table but i assume it has row for every property of post with meta_key = property name and mety_value = value

Comment: member is not a column in wp_postmeta, need to join with postmeta to filter by meta value.

Comment: I never said it is column, it is value in column wp_postmeta.meta_key and meta_value is 1 or 0 i guess. But yes that part i add need to be in having part becouse he already filter that row from wp_postmeta getting max value from meta_value column, updated my answer

Comment: I kept trying to add the case up with the initial select, and tried a join as Dharmang mentioned. Sorry I should've mentioned the difference between columns and values... but this worked perfectly. Thank you!